# Prove that $\lim_{x \to c} f(x)$ exists where $c$ is a cluster point

Tags: real-analysis

So I have this problem from Basic Analysis: Introduction to Real Analysis by Jiri Lebl for my analysis class.

3.1.10 Let $c$ be a cluster point of $A \subset \mathbb{R}$, and $f: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function. Suppose for every sequence $\{x_n\}$ in A, such that $\lim x_n = c$, the sequence $\{f(x_n)\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is Cauchy. **Prove that $\lim_{x \to c} f(x)$ exists.**

I have no idea what $x$ is supposed to be in $\lim_{x \to c} f(x)$. Is $x$ meant to be the elements of some arbitrary sequence in $A$? or does it have some other implied definition that I'm missing?

Answer (score 3):

Let $(c_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a sequence of numbers such that $\lim_{n\in\mathbb N}c_n=c$. Then the sequence $\bigl(f(c_n)\bigr)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a Cauchy sequence. But then this sequence must converge. Let $l$ be its limit. I shall prove that $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=l$.

Let $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a sequence of numbers such that $\lim_{n\in\mathbb N}x_n=c$. I want to prove that $\lim_{n\in\mathbb N}\bigl(f(x_n)\bigr)_{n\in\mathbb N}=l$. In order to do that, I consider the sequence $c_1,x_1,c_2,x_2,c_3,x_3,\ldots$ It converges (to $c$) too. Therefore, the sequence $f(c_1),f(x_1),f(c_2),f(x_2),f(c_3),f(x_3),\ldots$ is also a Cauchy sequence. But its subsequence $f(c_1),f(c_2)f(c_3)\ldots$ converges to $l$. So the whole sequence converge to $l$ and this implies that $\lim_{n\in\mathbb N}f(x_n)=l$.